# Java State Pattern with different implementation resulting in a difficult to understand error

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

Why is this java code not working.

```
abstract class Actor {
    Actor a = new HappyActor();
    abstract void act();
    void change() { a = new SadActor(); }
    void go() { a.act(); }
}

class HappyActor extends Actor {
    public void act() {
        System.out.println( ":)" );
    }
}

class SadActor extends Actor {
    public void act() {
        System.out.println( ":(" );
    }
}

public class TransmogrifyMe {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Actor s = new HappyActor();
        s.go(); // Prints ":)"
        s.change();
        s.go(); // Prints ":("
    }
}
```

It was my modification to the popular State pattern but not working unfortunately:
The assignment statement in the abstract class is called at the beginning of every constructor of a class inheriting from it. So the assignment statement tries to create an object of a derived class. i.e `Actor a = new HappyActor()` is called when the constructor of class `HappyActor` is called which results in a never ending loop of constructor call. Is this really what is happening?

The working version looks like the code below:

```
abstract class Actor {
    abstract void act();
}   

class HappyActor extends Actor {
    public void act() {
        System.out.println( ":)" );
    } 
}   

class SadActor extends Actor {
    public void act() {
        System.out.println( ":(" );
    } 
}   

class Stage {
    Actor a = new HappyActor();
    void change() { a = new SadActor(); }
    void go() { a.act(); }
}   

public class Transmogrify {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Stage s = new Stage();
        s.go(); // Prints ":)"
        s.change();
        s.go(); // Prints ":("
    }
}
```

The resulting error message in the first code is an unending loop of these two lines:

```
at Actor.<init>(TransmogrifyMe.java:6)
at HappyActor.<init>(TransmogrifyMe.java:12)
```

Is it possible to implement this kind of state change using inheritance. I found this in **Bruce Eckel**'s book **Thinking in Java** *In contrast you can't decide to inherit differently at run-time; that must be completely determined at compile-time*

Comment: "Is this really what is happening?" Yes. Beyond that, what's your question?

Comment: are you trying to just add more state transitions?

Comment: What can I do to implement the State pattern with Inheritance as opposed to composition?

Comment: it won't be the state pattern, if you use inheritance. This is the point of the pattern.

Comment: Ok. but is it even possible to implement this kind of state change using inheritance. I found this in **Bruce Eckel**'s book **Thinking in Java**
 _In contrast you can't decide to inherit differently at run-time; that must be completely determined at compile-time__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the class variable. Your methods should look like this:

```
State doSomething() {
  // do something, e.g. println.
  return new NextState();
  // or return this to stay in the current state.
}
```

and they are then used like this:

```
state = state.doSomething();
```

i.e. you `return` the *next* state.

e.g.

```
class HappyState implements State {
  public State change() {
    return new SadState();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when you attempt to create your first `HappyActor`. The default ctor needs first to create the guts of the `Actor`, and the first thing that does is tries to construct a `HappyActor`. Boom, infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code sample, which is indeed correct, Actor is the "State" of Stage. (Maybe Actor, being so self contained and independent from Stage, is more like a Strategy, but at this complexity level the difference is meaningless.)

Do you want to do something else?

Comment: What I want to implement is _state change with inheritance_. So let's avoid the Stage class. I want to create an Actor object (neither Happy nor Sad), and make this object act like a Happy actor sometimes and a sad one other times. So my question is is there a way of doing this without composition.

Comment: Rename the classes: the current Actor hierarchy to Brain, HappyBrain and SadBrain and the current Stage to Actor (holding a reference to a Brain). Any reference from an Actor to another Actor (or from a Brain to another Brain) is just plain wrong, even without circular constructor invocation chains.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it this way according to *Anony-Mousse* 's suggestion:

```
// StateChange.java
// Implementing the state pattern using inheritance

interface State {
    public State change();
    public void print();
}

class SadState implements State {
    public State change() {
        return new SadState();
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println( ":(" );
    }
}
class HappyState implements State {
    public State change() {
        return new SadState();
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println( ":)" );
    }
}

public class StateChange {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        State h = new HappyState();
        h.print(); // prints :)
        h = h.change();
        h.print(); // prints :(
        h = h.change();
        h.print(); // prints :)
    }
}
```

That's the best I could do!